# Override default Travis CI script for Java Gradle project

Tags: gradle, travis-ci

No matter what I write to `.travis.yml` Travis CI always executes `./gradlew assemble`. I would like to run `./gradlew test` instead.

Contents of my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java

script:
    - ./gradlew test
```

Feel free to fix my failed build:
https://github.com/RadoBuransky/scala-struct

Comment: My build uses the syntax `script: "gradle test"`. So I guess what you should have is `script: "./gradlew test"`

Comment: I tried that too and it also didn't work: https://github.com/RadoBuransky/scala-struct/blob/d1766827a6dd2fd24dc5c089c1ab98247a526e3d/.travis.yml

Comment: See this:  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-the-Installation-Step

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The script `./gradle assemble` is run as part of the `install` section of your build, it's the default.

If you want to skip this step, you can override it like so:

`install: true`

Docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Skipping-the-Installation-Step

Comment: Notice that it runs `assemble` first, then `check` as a second step (by default). `check` depends on `test`, so `test` runs by default.